# How to build stacks out of assembly code?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64

I am studying cybersecurity at the moment, and we learned how to build stacks out of an assembly code piece. But because of a lack of examples I am not sure about my idea of doing this.

The question is:

> Assume an empty stack and that the register `rax` is initially 1, all others 0. Draw the stack layout after the following code ﬁnishes, and mark where `rsp` points to. Note: the stack grows top to bottom.

```
push rax
inc rax
push rax
lea r11, [rip]
push r11
pop rcx
xor rcx, rcx
push rcx
mov rdx, 0xffff0000
push dx
pop r10w
push r10
add rax, 40
push rax
```

I know how `pop`, `push`, `inc` etc work (besides `lea` I am not so sure about).
I got the following result for the stack:

```
2
0x00 (or 0 not so sure About this)
0x00
0x00
0x00
42
```

and the `rsp` is by the entry with 42.

I looked around but did not find any example that looks similar to my exercise. I hope that someone can tell me where I made a mistake if I did one, because for me it looks wrong.

Comment: Use the markdown-like formatting system to revise your question so that the code is one instruction per line. This will help readers of your question scan your code for familiar assembly language idioms. For your own benefit, add a comment next to each line that shows how the stack looks after each instruction. You may learn enough from that that you can post the answer to this question yourself (which is allowed). Finally, some instruction sets are set up so that the top of the stack is accessible at all times via move r8, [rsp] and some via `move r8,[rsp-n]` so memorize that, it should help.

Comment: You seem to have missed the push rax at the beginning, when the value of rax is 1. You also seem to have overlooked that the values of r11 and dx that are pushed are popped again, so they don't affect the contents of the stack at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Draw the stack layout after the following code ﬁnishes, and mark where `rsp` points to.

Rather than trying to do this in your head you should write it out in detail:

```
code                  stack   register changes
--------------------  -----   ----------------
push rax              1

inc  rax                      rax=2
push rax              1
                      2

lea  r11, [rip]               r11=?
push r11              1
                      2
                      ?

pop  rcx              1       rcx=?
                      2

xor  rcx, rcx                 rcx=0
push rcx              1
                      2
                      0

mov  rdx, 0xffff0000          rdx=0xFFFF0000 -> dx=0
push dx               1
                      2
                      0
                      0

pop  r10w             1       r10w=0 -> r10=0
                      2
                      0

push r10              1
                      2
                      0
                      0

add  rax, 40                  rax=42
push rax              1
                      2
                      0
                      0
                     42 <-- RSP points below here
```

> ```
> lea r11, [rip]
> push r11
> pop rcx
> ```

and

> ```
> mov rdx, 0xffff0000
> push dx
> pop r10w
> ```

have no real influence on the final stack. They did however change registers `R10` and `R11`.